# How to improve a complicated and poor SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables for a messaging application:

```
`messaging_message`
 - thread_id
 - content
 - timestamp
 - sender_id 

`messaging_messagestatus`
 - thread_id # though redundant here, makes messaging queries much easier
 - message
 - recipient_id
 - status
```

A few notes:

- Each message will have two messagestatus entries that refer to it, one for each user in the message thread.
- There may be multiple messages in a single message thread.
- A user may delete a message (status='deleted'), one user deleting a message will obviously not delete that same message for the other user in the thread.

Doing my best with a rudimentary knowledge of SQL, I have created a query to get:

**Given a user, get all distinct non-deleted threads, showing 1) thread_id; 2) message_id // 3) timestamp // 4) content of the most recent message in that thread; 5) who the other person in the message thread is; and 6) whether the user sent the most recent message**. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT thread_id, message_id, timestamp, content,
(SELECT DISTINCT recipient_id FROM messaging_messagestatus ms WHERE ms.thread_id=thread_id     
  AND recipient_id !=4) as other_recipient,
(CASE WHEN sender_id=4 THEN True ELSE False END) as sent_last_message

FROM
( SELECT m.thread_id, recipient_id, timestamp, m.id as message_id, content, sender_id
    FROM messaging_messagestatus ms
    INNER JOIN messaging_message m
    ON ms.message_id = m.id
WHERE recipient_id = 4 AND m.thread_id NOT in 
    ( SELECT thread_id FROM messaging_messagestatus WHERE status='deleted' 
      AND recipient_id = 4)

ORDER BY timestamp DESC) combined GROUP BY thread_id
```

This query DOES WORK and will give me something like:

```
thread_id   message_id  timestamp       content         other_recipient   sent_last_message
2           3       2012-06-09 13:02:08 newest message  80                 1
```

With about 20k message rows / 35k status rows, the first query takes about 14s! Subsequent queries about 3s.

Comment: Since it looks like a relation 1:1, isn't the best choice just to merge the tables?

Comment: It may be ugly, but it works. The real question is, how does it perform? I'd only be interested in rewriting it if it performed poorly.

Comment: @HackedByChinese: I'm not sure, my table only has 5 rows, I'm writing the app now

Comment: @user1383058: Testing on 5 rows is a great way to write an application that performs fine in testing but fails miserably in production. Get some test data in your database. Grab some suitable data from somewhere and use it to populate your database. Or randomly generate data if you can't find anything.

Comment: @MarkByers: with a `message` table with 4k rows and a `status` table with 8k rows the query takes 152 ms to complete on the first time. Though to be honest, I have no idea whether that is 'slow'. How is that usually determined?

Comment: @HackedByChinese see comment above

Comment: @user1383058: More interesting is to see how the time grows as the input grows. If you have twice as many rows, does the time stay almost the same? Double? More than double?

Comment: @MarkByers with about 20k message rows / 35k status rows, the first query takes about 14s! Subsequent queries about 3s

Comment: @user1383058: That doesn't sound very good to me. You should certainly be able to rewrite your query to return results in under 1 second for 30k rows. How many rows do you expect when your site goes live?

Answer (score 0):

You should merge those tables.  Having two separate tables that have such directly related data is not good programming.  This would eliminate any joins between those two data sources and make querying data easier and faster.

Comment: How could I merge the tables if there isn't a 1:1 relationship between them? There will be multiple status entries for each message.

Comment: Also, what if one user deletes a message but the other user does not? How would that be handled?

Comment: @MarkByers I think that should be there in the 'two notes' right underneath the table definition.

Comment: Not necessarily true that. Optional extension to an entity for instance.